# What format is data sent and returned when dealing with serial communication

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, serial-port

This is a relatively noobish question but I having a hard time getting it.

Here is what I'm faced with:

Im using the 32feet libraries for bluetooth communication between a windows mobile (running compact framework ) device and a medical device.

This medical device has outlined communication instructions.   They appear to be very straightforward but there's a part of it I'm not understanding... namely the format that the data is sent and received.

The documentation claims I need to send certain strings to the device to give it commands.   For example If I swnd it "ver::CR" the device should reply with v92:as0001::CR".  I'm assuming for now that the CR tags are Carriage returns.

Now the question is what format do I send this data in.   Does data always have to be IN the form of a byte array?

Im using a BinaryWriter which has a million overloads...one of which being a string. Since the device appears to be expecting 'text' do I just send it text?  Since it claims to return a string... Do I just assume it's a string

It uses NetworkStream for data it seems.   Can I simply send a steering and expect a steering in return?

I'm essentially lost on the format of the data to go to and from the device.

Summary: when sending data using virtual comm port,  what format may that data be in and what format should I expect to receiveitr in.

I'll gladly be more clear if the question is to vague.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I've not used 32feet.Net, and of course I've not used your medical device.

When documentation says CR or  they usually mean a carriage return character: a hex 0D value.  This is a very common serial communications end-of-message indicator.

Most serial devices expect data using only the ASCII character set. Chances are that your binary writer accepts a string value and sends the equivalent ASCII characters to the medical device though the Bluetooth connection.

You would do something like:

```
  string myText = "ver":
  myWriter.SendText(myText + "\n");
```

An alternate that might work would be to code this:

```
  string myText = "ver":
  myWriter.SendText(myText + Environment.NewLine);
```

If that doesn't work for you, you need to change the string, with the concatenated carriage return character, into a byte array using ASCII encoding, then stream the byte array out to the device. You might need to fiddle with the carriage return character, maybe trying "\r\n", depending on what your device needs.